# Count of group dimensions item in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm fairly new to tableau and I'm having the following issue. Below is a sample of the data I'm using.

```
Customer No | Item
___________________
 1            A
 1            B
 2            A
 3            A
 4            A
 4            B
 5            B
 6            A
```

I'm trying to get a count of how many customers bought Item A and B. So far I tried doing a separate group by combining A and B but I get the total result of 8. I also tried doing a calculation and I'm getting the same result of 8. Can someone please point me to the right direction on how to get this result. Thanks!

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
Item| Count
A             5
B             3
A and B       2
```

Comment: You'll want to use the countd aggregate function and then turn on the grand total. Switch the grand total to use the countd aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sam. I made some edit on my original post. I'm trying to get 3 columns on my graph Item A , Item B and Item A and B. How do you suggest I make the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your exact dataset and pasted it into Tableau so you could see a couple of examples.

Here's how you can see the number of customers who purchased an individual item, plus the number of customers who purchased both items.

Your calculation will be:

```
IF { FIXED [Customer No]: COUNTD([Item]) } = 1 THEN
    [Item]
ELSE
    'Both A and B'
END
```

And you'll need to set your view up to look like this:

[image]

Below are ways you can see when both items were purchased.

1. Boolean OR
   The calculation you'll want to use is:

   ATTR([ITEM]) = 'A' OR ATTR([ITEM]) = 'B'

And you'll want to set up your view to look like this:
[image]

2. A, B or Both
   If you would like a bit more specificity in your result, you might try:

   IF ATTR([Item]) = 'A' THEN
       'A'
   ELSEIF ATTR([Item]) = 'B' THEN
       'B'
   ELSE
       'BOTH'
   END

Replacing the previous calculation with the new looks like this:
[image]

3. More than 1 item
   If the specific items purchased don't matter, you could use this logic.

   COUNTD([Item]) > 1

Replacing the previous calculation with this one would look like:
[image]

4. More than 1 Item using a window function (probably overkill)
   The calculation you'll need to use is:

   WINDOW_COUNT(COUNTD([Item]))

Because this is a Window function, we'll need to specify how it's calculated across our dimensions. To do this click the down arrow on the right-hand side of the pill and select Edit Table Calculation...

[image]

You'll then need to set these settings:

[image]

I'll add the calculation we created in the first example ([A and B]) to the filter shelf and select True. That should give you something that looks like:

[image]

5. More than 1 item using a Level of Detail expression
   The calculation for this example is:

   { EXCLUDE [Item]: COUNTD([Item]) }

You'll view should look like:
[image]

As you can see Tableau is quite flexible. Hope these examples were helpful!

Comment: Hello Rob , thanks for the response and the screenshots it really helpful. What am trying to get on my graph is 3 columns of items: Items A , Item B and (Items A and B) and on the rows a distinct count of customer no. Will this approach work too?

Comment: Actually, yes. I have updated the answer to show you one way I was able to get the answer. I'm sure there are plenty of others ways as well. It the calculations in Tableau start to get too tricky I would create the calculations externally, then simply use Tableau to visualize the results in an engaging/informative way.

Comment: @SQLnoob if that solution works for you would you mind marking the answer as correct? Otherwise, please let me know what more I can help you with. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Rob thank you so much the calculation worked !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Tableau’s set feature to approach problems like this.

For example, right click on the field [Customer No] in the data pane (i.e. left sidebar) and choose the “Create Set” command. Click “Use All” at the top of the set panel and then click the **Condition** tab. Define the set using the condition `MAX([Item] = “A”)`. Name the set “Customers who bought A”.

[image]

Similarly, create a set of customers who bought item B. You can then select both sets in the data pane, and create a combined set to be the intersection, that is, customers who bought both an item A and an item B.

You can think of a set as either a mathematical set of the members of a field that belong to the set (i.e. a set of customer ids) or as Boolean function defined for each data record in the data source indicating whether that data record is associated with the set (i.e. a Boolean function that operates on transactions to say whether the associated customer ID is in the set. A key to keep in mind for the condition formulas used here is that the condition is an aggregate formula, operating on a block of data records for a customer ID to determine whether the customer ID is in the set.

Once you have defined your sets of interest, you can use them in many ways - in calculated fields, as filters, as dimensions on shelves in a visualization, in set actions, to combine with other sets ...

To define a measure that counts the customers in a set, create a calculated field such as “[Num A Customers]” as `COUNTD(if [Customers who bought A] then [Customer ID] end)` Do the same for whatever other sets you are interested in. Then you can use those measures (probably with Measure Names and Measure Values) to make your viz.

[image]

Comment: Hello Alex thanks for your response ill give it a try and ill let you know how it goes . Thanks!

Comment: Good one, I was looking for a way to do this with sets, but don't have much experience with them. Thanks for sharing!